# Get Index of a string from list of string

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to get values from a list. In the result I need the **index** of the value in the resulting list also. I dont have any idea how to get it. Can someone get me some ideas. Following is the code which i use.

```
        List<string> Lst1 = new List<string>();
        Lst1.Add("a");
        Lst1.Add("ab");
        Lst1.Add("c");
        Lst1.Add("d");

        List<string> result = Lst1.Select(x => x.Substring(0, 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: So you need index and value both in the result right ? IF that's the case you need the result as `Dictionary`

Comment: @CoderofCode: Not necessarily; an anonymous type might suffice as well. Depends on what they want to do with it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear how you want to incorporate the original list index for the string in your `result`. Please edit the question so that it's clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) has an overload that gives the index too, so you can just use that. Note that you cannot store both the string and the index in a `List<string>`, so you maybe need a `List<Tuple<string, int>>` instead. Also note, that in a list, each element already has an index, so you don’t really need this anyway.

```
List<Tuple<string, int>> result = Lst1.Select(
        (x, i) => new Tuple<string, int>(x.Substring(0, 1), i)).ToList();
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: That'd be `Tuple.Create`, I guess.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: type inference doesn't work for constructors. But, that's why Microsoft provided the `Tuple.Create()` methods. So `Tuple.Create(x.Substring(0, 1), i)` works (and IMHO is preferable to specifying the type parameters explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

You can use second overload of [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
 var result = Lst1.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i });
```

[Working Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aWA3Fz).